# Display PDF with Read-Only view - SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, sharepoint-foundation, pdf

I'm using SP2007. I need to Render a PDF in a Document Library, in a page. But i need to restrict users from downloading, coping content or even printing the PDF file. Can this be directly in a PDF viewer done maybe using
 `<embed>` or `<object>`

OR

Is there any tool that would be be able to use/customize according to my requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

I get this question a lot (I work for a SharePoint PDF Conversion Company) and have recently started to recommend [Foxit's Server based SharePoint PDF Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/sharepoint/).

This should be a lot easier to implement than a full IRM solution.

Comment: Thanks ! The downloads are for SharePoint 2010 & 2013, Is there a version for SharePoint 2007 as well?

Comment: You would need to ask Foxit.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is IRM, Information Rights Management and its built in to SP2007 (better in recent versions though).

Have a look at the following link for some additional information, its not the most straight forward to implement but could fulfill your needs.

[IRM on Technet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/apply-information-rights-management-to-a-list-or-library-HA010154148.aspx)